# Find many unique sublists from a master list

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have a list such as this:

```
original = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and another one of which I will find the sublists:

```
queries = [1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1]
```

I want all the sublists which include only one instance of the original list. So in this example, I would get:

```
sublists = [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2], [1] ]
```

and my original would be left with:

```
original = [5]
```

How would I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 0):

One slightly indirect approach would be to utilise the `collections.Counter` library object:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import zip_longest, repeat

original = [1, 2, 3, 4]
query = [1, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3, 2, 1]

cnts = Counter(query)
# cnts: Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 3: 1})
sublists = zip_longest(*map(repeat, original, map(cnts.pop, original)))
# this creates the approprate number of copies of 1, 2, 3, 4 and (via
# zip_longest) shuffles them into lists with max one occurrence each
# sublists are padded with None's -- [(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, None, None), (1, None, None, None)]
sublists = list(map(list, map(filter, repeat(bool), sublists)))
# None's are removed -- [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2], [1]]
leftovers = list(filter(cnts.__contains__, query))
# [5]
```